# Linux softraid: Can disk image files mounted via loop device be located on a raid 1?

Tags: linux, disk-image, raid-1

I want to use a softraid mirror for my new Linux installation (VoidLinux) -- complete mirror of swap and /.

Now I also want to mount some directories (e.g. /home) via loop device from a disk image file that itself is located at the raid 1 mirror.

Now my question is: is the disk image file properly mirrored as well? I do not know the technics behind loop mounts in Linux. I fear that every write access into the image file via the loop device is not going thru the softraid layer and so will not been properly written to both image files of the mirror.

Do you know if this configuration will work as I intended?

Thanks for all insight you can spread to me ...

Regards,
chi.

Comment: Why do you want to mount directories from an image file instead of just putting them as a regular partition on the raid? Think about the logic of a raid 1 and you will know what happens if a file that resides on it is changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Usually while I use BSD systems I was used to use several different partitions (slices/labels in BSD speak). But every Linux system seem to advocate to put all the stuff under /. As I still want to limit how much space /home or /var/log can maximally take I thought to use disk image files with the appropiate size, mount them and got the best of two worlds. Use as many space where I want and limit it where I do not want too much to be used. It seems to be more flexible this way without different partitions either in primary or even in extended partition format :-)

Comment: Even in Linux you can freely use mount points and use different partitions for it. Using just `/` is often the easiest option for inexperienced users. Separating `/home`, `/boot` and so on isn't unusual. `fstab` is important in this scenario. It shouldn't be a problem to setup e.g. sda1 or md1 to be used for `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use a softraid mirror for my new Linux installation (VoidLinux) -- complete mirror of swap and /.

Mirroring swap sounds quite useless, but as you wish ;-)

> Now I also want to mount some directories (e.g. /home) via loop device from a disk image file that itself is located at the raid 1 mirror.

As long as this disk image is, basically a file on a FS living in the RAID 1, yes.

> Now my question is: is the disk image file properly mirrored as well? I do not know the technics behind loop mounts in Linux. I fear that every write access into the image file via the loop device is not going thru the softraid layer and so will not been properly written to both image files of the mirror.

You're wrong. Disk image is nothing but a file on the filesystem. 
Soft RAID, just as hardware RAID, works under the filesystem layer, at "block device" level. Whatever you do on the resulting /dev/dmXX will be mirrored.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I am convinced that it will work the way I intended :-)

Why the mirrored swap? I have learned that if my swap is mirrored my system will still work if one HD fails! If my swap was not mirrored and that HD where the swap is located to fails, then my system will crash!

Am I wrong?

Comment: Nowadays, with server with huge amount of RAM, swap became quite useless. But you're right, if your applications need swap, putting it on RAID array make your whole stack resilient to a disk failure.

Comment: Thank you again for your insight! About nowadays RAM -- you cannot know I use a repurposed machine with 1 GB RAM only to serve as a small web and mail server :-)